Is the function $g(n) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n) - 1}\left(\frac{1}{n-p_{k}}\right)$ bounded?
This is related to my other question here (that is, the terms of this sum are the reciprocals of that one).
Define a function $g(n)$ that takes the sum of the reciprocals of the difference between $n$ and all the primes below it. In other words,
$$g(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n) - 1}\left(\frac{1}{n-p_{k}}\right),$$
where $p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime (with $2 = p_1$) and $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes less than or equal to $n$. For example,
$$g(12) = \frac{1}{12-11} + \frac{1}{12-7} + \frac{1}{12-5} + \frac{1}{12-3} + \frac{1}{12-2} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10}\approx 1.55.$$
My question is this:

Is $g(n)$ bounded?

While investigating this function I've come up with some integer sequences that I haven't been able to find in OEIS. Primarily, the list of $n$ for which $g(n)$ is greater than any previous $n$ (I've computed up to $500,$$000$):
$$3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 20, 44, 74, 110, 200, 284, 620, 830, 1304, 1880, 2714, 3470, 5660, 9440, 65720, 69500, 81050, 88820, 113174, 284750...$$
Related, but not identical, to my original question is the question of whether this sequence continues infinitely or not. (That is, if it continues infinitely, $g(n)$ still may be bounded, but if it has a finite number of terms, $g(n)$ cannot be unbounded.) For reference, here's the list of $g(n)$ (rounded to the nearest thousandth unless the difference is smaller) associated with the above sequence:
$$0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.583, 1.7, 1.72, 1.845, 1.908, 1.984, 2.09, 2.123, 2.138, 2.177, 2.192, 2.247, 2.257, 2.2766, 2.2768, 2.341, 2.374, 2.388, 2.408, 2.444, 2.467, 2.521, 2.553...$$
All of the terms in the above sequence are $1$ more than a prime (the reason should be self-evident); here is the sequence of the indices of those primes (again, treating $2$ as $p_1$):
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 21, 29, 46, 61, 114, 145, 213, 289, 396, 487, 746, 1170, 6567, 6902, 7935, 8605, 10727, 24824...$$
I can't find a pattern; even the gaps between them seem erratic (note the jump from $1170$ to $6567$ and then the small step to $6902$). How would I go about figuring this out?
Thanks for your help!

Writing the sum more naturally as $\sum_{p\le x-1} \frac1{x-p}$: I think this hinges on what we can prove about admissible tuples of integers (sets of integers that do not cover all the residue classes modulo any prime). Conjecturally, if ${a_1,\dots,a_k}$ is any admissible tuple, then $x-a_1,\dots,x-a_k$ will be simultaneously prime infinitely often, and thus the sum will be at least as large as $1/a_1+\cdots+1/a_k$. I wasn't able to find what it known (or believed) about whether these sums of reciprocals of admissible sets can be arbitrarily large.

By partial summation one can get that this sum (in the form of the comment of @GregMartin) is $$\pi(x-1) - \int_{2}^{x-1} \frac{\pi(u)}{(x-u)^2} du$$ Not sure if one can make any progress from here

That's certainly a start... is it possible to integrate $\pi(x)$ or is that impossible? It may not be necessary to prove or disprove boundedness, anyway.

@Mathemagician314 You can use an asymptotics like $\pi(u) \sim \operatorname{Li}(u)$.

$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}$
A tuple of distinct positive integers $(a_1, \cdots, a_k)$ is admissible if for any prime $p$, they don't form a complete residual system modulo $p$.
Continuing on Greg's comment, I think I can show the following.
Proposition: For any $N > 0$, there exists an admissible tuple with reciprocal sum at least $N$.
Proof: We take some $ M> 0$. For each prime $p \leq M$, we independently sample a uniformly random integer $a_p$ between $\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor$ and $p$. Let $A$ be the set integers in $[1, M]$ that is not congruent to $a_p$ modulo $p$ for any $p \leq M$. Then by definition, $A$ is admissible. We compute the expected value of the reciprocal sum of $A$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$\mathbb{E} \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} = \sum_{a = 1}^M \frac{1}{a} \mathbb{P}(a \in A).$$
We now estimate $\mathbb{P}(a \in A)$. Note that
$$\mathbb{P}(a \in A) = \prod_{p \in [1, M]} (1 - \mathbb{P}(a \equiv a_p \bmod{p}))$$
where the product is over primes.
If $p > 2a^2$, then by construction, we can never have $a \equiv a_p \bmod{p}$. Otherwise, there are $p - \floor{\sqrt{p}} + 1$ choices for the residual class $a_p$, so the probability that $a \equiv a_p \bmod{p})$ is at most $\frac{1}{p - \floor{\sqrt{p}} + 1}$. Thus we have
$$\prod_{p \in [1, M]} (1 - \mathbb{P}(a \equiv a_p \bmod{p})) \geq \prod_{p \in [1, 2a^2]} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p - \sqrt{p} + 1}\right).$$
We observe that the constant
$$K:=\prod_p \left(1 - \frac{1}{p - \sqrt{p} + 1}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$$
is strictly greater than $0$. So we have
$$\prod_{p \in [1, M]} (1 - \mathbb{P}(a \equiv a_p \bmod{p})) \geq K \prod_{p \in [1, 2a^2]} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$
By Merten's third theorem, we have for some constant $K' > 0$ and every $a \geq 2$.
$$\prod_{p \in [1, 2a^2]} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \geq \frac{K'}{\log(2a^2)} \geq \frac{K'}{3\log(a)}.$$
So we conclude that, for some constant $C > 0$
$$\mathbb{P}(a \in A) \geq \frac{C}{\log(a)}.$$
Thus we obtain
$$\mathbb{E} \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} = \sum_{a = 1}^M \frac{1}{a} \mathbb{P}(a \in A) \geq \sum_{a = 2}^M \frac{C}{a\log(a)} = \Omega(\log\log M).$$
Taking $M$ sufficiently large, we conclude that
$$\mathbb{E} \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} > N$$
so there is an admissible set whose reciprocal sum is greater than $N$. QED.
Assuming the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture, for every admissible tuple $A$, there exists some $n$ such that $\{n - a: a \in A\}$ are all prime numbers. For this $n$, we have
$$g(n) \geq \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}.$$
By the proposition above, we conclude that $g(n)$ is unbounded.

Very nice strategy!

Whoa, cool! Thanks so much for this! Does the fact that $g(n)$ is unbounded have any further possible implications, or is it just a little fun piece of pure mathematics? (Also, can anyone think of a better name or symbol for the function than $g(n)$? That was just the placeholder I used, but I'm sure there's some combination of some letters that would make more sense and be more unique.)
